# Getting started -Importing files

Tags: kml, dxf, dwg

How do I start?

I want to open a DXF or a DWG file and then to export it to a KML file to be used in google earth.

Have no idea how to start doing so.

Comment: What software do you have available? If you're open to suggestion perhaps look at GDAL/OGR which has a driver for KML http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html and DXF/DWG http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html and http://www.gdal.org/drv_cad.html so an OGR2OGR call http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html might meet your needs.

Comment: I use Autocad 2018 and then change the inxtension into a DXF file, then use QGIS the latest version. I managed to do the convertion this morning, thanks